# Cannot build native apps after upgrading to 22.04 from 20

Tags: 22.04, ffmpeg, c++

It seems that I get stuck going down a rabbit hole when I try to build anything depending on ffmpeg, avlib, and gstreamer since switching to ubuntu 22; its incredibly frustrating and I wonder if the community has any guidance as to the best way to handle these situations besides reverting back to the older version.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec-dev : Depends: libavcodec59 (= 7:5.1.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav0)
 libavdevice59 : Depends: libavcodec59 (= 7:5.1.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav0)
                 Depends: libavfilter8 (= 7:5.1.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav0)
                 Depends: libavformat59 (= 7:5.1.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav0)
 libavfilter-dev : Depends: libavfilter8 (= 7:5.1.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav0)
 libavformat-dev : Depends: libavformat59 (= 7:5.1.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav0)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: The `.sav0` package suffix suggests the issue is related to one or more of [these PPAs](https://launchpad.net/~savoury1)